# Why there is a match for third place in football but not in cricket?

Tags: cricket, football, cricket-world-cup

Why there is a match to decide third place between the losing semi-finalists in [football](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2014_FIFA_World_Cup#Third_place_play-off), but not in cricket?

Comment: These are two very different sports, and it's really hard to compare them. Also note that not all football cups have a third place match, the world cup is one of the few that has it. For example there is no third place match in the UEFA European Championship.

Answer (score 3):

Cricket and football are totally different sports. There is no similarity between both sports. Every aspects of both sports are different (with some exceptions). So same apply to their major tournaments like world cups as well. We can't really compare tournament's rules of different sports. This is totally up to the tournament organizer like FIFA for football and ICC for cricket.

Comment: Well, this answer doesn't provide any info. You could have mentioned some reasons why FIFA does this - Marketing, financial etc.

Comment: @SahuKahn - Well the question itself does not ask "Why FIFA organises a match for third place?" the actual question is "Why there is no match for third place in cricket when other sport has it?". If you are curious to know you may ask a separate question.

Comment: I used the FIFA example, as you had used it in the answer. My point is, we know there are differences in different sports like football, cricket. The question tries to understand why there is a difference. So saying different sports are different, doesn't help much.

Comment: @SahuKahn - I think you didn't get the point here. If you are trying to get the answer for "why is there a different tournament schedule (or a rule) between two entire different sports?", then you will get board, opinion based answers. Also, How does it make sense to ask for a reason for *any* difference between completely different sports?

Comment: The question does ask why is there a different type of match scheduled for football and not cricket. So there is a talk about diff between the 2 sports. Which in itself is broad.

Comment: The answer below does bring the point of money, which is a very valid point. That's the point i was trying to make. The answer should try to address the question asked.

Answer (score 2):

It's not in every competition in football:

I think it's only in World Cup and European Cup ...it might be in other continental turnaments too.

But in not in competitions linke UEFA Champions League or European League.
Nor in the cup competitions in England, Germany, Italay ...

And this game is because FIFA/UEFA can earn some money with it. There is a discussion about the sense of such a game. And I think most players/coaches would prefere NOT playing this game. There is often no motivation and so it'll be a horrible match.